# Data Quality Services (DQS) Error after installing SQL Server 2012 SP2

Tags: sql-server, data-quality-services

When I open the DQS client, I get this error message:

Message Id: VerificationFrameworkVersionNotCompatible
A new version of .NET or Data Quality Services was installed on this machine. In order to continue to work with DQS please run 'DqsInstaller.exe -upgrade'.

However, when I run DQSInstaller.exe, I get this message:

DQS Installer has detected a previous DQS installation under this SQL Server instance.  Running DQS installer will remove the previous installation, together with all the knowledge stored in it.

Will I lose all my knowledge bases?  Is there an upgrade path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DQSInstaller as stated, but it WILL remove any Knowledge Bases and projects that you already have in place.  I had this same issue due to installing SP2, but was able to work around it using the Import/Export feature in DQSInstaller.

Before you run the upgrade, run DQSInstaller with the -exportkbs argument in order to backup your installation.

```
dqsinstaller.exe –exportkbs c:\DQSBackup.dqsb
```

Then run the upgrade path to get a fresh install, and run DQSInstaller again with -importkbs to load your Knowledge Bases back in to the new installation.

```
dqsinstaller.exe –importkbs c:\DQSBackup.dqsb
```

This is exactly how I was able to resolve this issue in my environment, and retain the configuration/knowledge that had already been built up in DQS.

Source: [MSDN - Export and Import DQS Knowledge Bases using DQSInstaller.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh759340.aspx)